# Can such a transformation be implemented by using just polarizers?

Tags: quantum-gate, optical-quantum-computing

Consider a transformation $U_a=\sigma_z^{a_1}\otimes...\sigma_z^{a_N}$, here $\sigma_z$ is the Pauli Z operator. $a_i$ is either 0 or 1. Hence, $\sigma_z^{0}=I$ where $I$ is identity matrix.

If I use polarization of light as a qubit, can I implement this transformation using just polarizers? Please help me justify it.

Comment: what do you mean by "please help me justify it"? Where did you encounter this statement?

Comment: Do you know about wave plates?

Answer (score 1):

With polarizers you can implement projections. The Pauli Z oerator has an eigenvalue $-1$, so no, you cannot implement $U_a$ with only polarizers.

Comment: Why does an eigenvalue -1 create a problem?

Comment: @ChetanWaghela A product of projectors will not have a negative eigenvalue, so this is one way to see why you will need some more building blocks to implement $U_a$